# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier while table creation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE T_Option_Details (
  Option_Id    NUMBER(2),
  Question_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Option       VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL);
```

Error at line 3
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: CREATE TABLE t_Option_Details (option_Id NUMBER(2) , Question_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, option1 VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL

Answer (score 2):

`OPTION` is an oracle reserved keyword, Try with some other column name like this,

```
CREATE TABLE T_Option_Details(
     Option_Id   NUMBER(2),
     Question_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
     OPTION_N      VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL)
```