# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier on oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Today I create a table in SQL command mode on apex.oracle.com but this command does not execute table. but why

```
CREATE TABLE DESIGBEH (
  DID       NUMBER(10),
  TYPE      VARCHAR2(30),
  PARANT    VARCHAR2(30),
  DEPTNAME  VARCHAR2(30),
  DNAME     VARCHAR2(30),
  DESC      VARCHAR2(100),
  STATUS    VARCHAR2(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (DID) USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20208918/1509264

Comment: `type`, `desc` are reserved words in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00904 means that one of your column name is invalid. The culprits are the columns `TYPE` and `DESC`. They are on the list of the many reserved words in Oracle.

See the full list here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: Thanks & pls you can help me : How to create a parent table ?

Comment: @MonirKhan for foreign key : `create table prtTable( id_did number primary key, abc varchar2(100));` `CREATE TABLE DESIGBEH ( DID NUMBER(10),  ...  ,CONSTRAINT fk_prttable
    FOREIGN KEY (did)
    REFERENCES prtTable(id_did))`

Comment: Create another question if you have a different issue. And accept the answer if it fixes your current one.

Answer (score 0):

problem is due to preserved word `DESC` used as a column name. You may try to use `DESC_` as column name. i.e. you can not use some preserved words as column name, like words `CREATE`, `TABLE`, `AS`, `DROP` etc.